# In wordpress AIT theme how can we set default map location in zoom formate

Tags: wordpress

Hey friends, 
            I am using AIT theme in my wordpress but please let me know how can i set in default my map location in header map

Rekha

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem with my own AIT-themed Directory site.  As far as I've been able to see through all AIT forums -- the default zoom for the main map is automatically set and cannot be changed.  It scales/zooms out to show all of the businesses, etc. that you have placed on the map itself.  The only way to zoom in on an item is if there is only one present in the map.  With two or more present it defaults back to the automatic zoom.  Frustrating, I know.